# .htaccess dynamic no-cache based on cookie

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, cache-control

I'm writing an online website editor where people can make pages and edit their content in their own websites. The system writes real .html pages, and real .css pages. The problem is two-fold: I want to disable cache of everything on their site while they're editing, so they always get the latest versions of everything, and I don't want to disable the cache entirely for everyone, so that the sites perform well. My thought was that I would look for the cookie that identifies a logged-in user, and use that in .htaccess to determine when to disable cache. I haven't found anything in stackoverflow, askapache, Google, etc, that deals with setting specific request headers based on cookies, but through these resources I was able to cobble together the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mode=.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=CACHECONTROL:max-age=604800]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*mode=.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=CACHECONTROL:no-cache]

Header set Cache-Control "%{CACHECONTROL}e" env=CACHECONTROL
```

This does work in the sense that the cookie is detected and the request header is changing, but it doesn't seem to be making any difference in the users' experience. They are still having tremendous problems with caching, where they make a change to their template, publish, and the go to a page to edit there and see the older version of their template still.

If they go to their website not logged in, and they get the max-age cache, does that mean that my .htaccess file is not being checked after they're logged? Is there a better variable to set for this? I'm at my wit's end and could really use some other eyeballs on this.

Thanks in advance!
Mike

*edit* This is what I'm using now:

```
Header set Cache-Control "must-revalidate, private"
Header set Expires "-1"
```

It seems like the "must-revalidate" is more important than specifying a timeout age, and it seems to be helping. It's also nice that I can use the same headers for all users, which means less server-side programming and more static served files. It's still not perfect though, and we're still getting the occasional complaint about caching.

Comment: What are the _other_ response headers that might be related to caching? Or are there _two_ Cache-Control: headers? This smells to me like it might be conflicting headers, something that's fairly easy to do in .htaccess (also easy to fix once you know about it). Also specify "no-cache, no-store" rather than just "no-cache" to be more sure you nuke the browser's local cache rather than just in-network/proxy caches (it's "paranoia" that doesn't seem necessary, but it doesn't hurt and it might help). And what versions of apache and browsers exhibit this problem?

Comment: @starkraving-Another guess: Server headers give the browser _permission_ to do things, but don't actually _require_ the browser to do them. (ex: the FF UI gives the user fine-tuning choices-- Once per session, Every time I view the page, When the page is out of date (default), or Never.) Also, a "no-cache" header from the server will prevent caching of the new version, but will _not_ flush the old version out of the browser cache. Although I'm a bit fuzzy, I know the solution has to happen on the client side and has something to do with appending useless-but-unique query strings to the URL.